# How to ommit 1062 error, ie add only not-duplicate rows without causing error?

Tags: php, mysql

Duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` VALUES ("val1"), ("abc")
```

or

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` SET columnname1="val1"
```

Comment: ahh sorry, it's a bit early in the morning *grin*

Answer (score 0):

Check your table first if the pair of values already exists. If it does simply don't make the insert.

Answer (score 0):

three things you can do.

- You can check before insert if the key pair already exists.
- Look at [INSERT IGNORE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)
- You can wrap your code in try catch if you are using PDO to override this error. I personally am not in favor of this but works great

Answer (score 0):

You can use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html). No need to check anything - it brings additional overhead.